# Typus and Rails 3.1 - missing constant AdminsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, typus

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc4'
gem 'typus', :git => 'http://github.com/typus/typus', :branch => '3-1-unstable'
```

Obviously the name of the Git-branch suggests that it's error prone, but I think I might be missing something simple here. According to the documentation *rails g typus* and *rails g typus:migration* should be enough to get going.

My problem is that I'm missing the AdminsController, after migrating and navigating to 0.0.0.0:3000 I get greeted by

> uninitialized constant AdminsController

and there is no AdminsController.rb in app/controllers. Is this a bug in the 3.1 branch or am I missing something in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was entirely my fault. I didn't have a clean admin namespace like I should have.

Answer (score 0):

Teddy bear theory strikes again. Navigating to /admin/session/ greets me with a login page. I get the feeling that navigating to /admin/ should still produce some output and not an error message though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the commits it's so bleeding edge that's probably a bug.

I see that you already notified developers by opening a ticket, hopefully they'll look into it soon.

Happens to me also all the time with stuff that is trying to be 3.1 compatible, for which I create a patch when it's possible.

Cheers